# How can i retrieve data in my child UICollectionView from my parent UICollectionViewCell - swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Suppose I have a `ParentCollectionViewController` which has the data called `assetID`.

This data is also available in the `ParentCollectionViewControllerCell`.

How can I pass this data in the `ChildCollectionView` which is located in each `ParentCollectionViewControllerCell`.

[Here's the image](https://ibb.co/f0RH5Vp)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that on each parent collectionviewcell you have child collectionview inside it?

Comment: Yes that's correct! @RajatGupta

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: where are you writing datasource for your ChildCollectionView, I mean into your ParentCollectionViewController or into ParentCollectionViewControllerCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier alternative.

1. Declare a function setData() in the ChildCollectionView file.

   ```
   func setData(dataString: String){
      print(dataString, "data you wanted to pass")
   }
   ```
2. Take an outlet of the ChildCollectionView from the storyboard into the ParentCollectionViewCell
3. Call the setData(data) function in ParentCollectionViewCell using the outlet and pass the data into it. Like this:

   ```
   var dataString: String! {
     didSet {
       childCollectionViewOutlet.setData(dataString: dataString)
     }
   }
   ```
4. And voila! You will now have the data available in the desired ChildCollectionView. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to send the data first you need to register child collectionviewcell in ParentCollectionViewControllerCell. This you will do in awakeFromNib().

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   childCollectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "childCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "childCollectionViewCell")
   childCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

So it means you have all the delegates and datasource of child collectionview in ParentCollectionViewControllerCell. So you will send the data through cellForItemAtindexPath:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "childCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! childCollectionViewCell
        cell.bindAssetid(strAssetId: assetID!)
        return cell
    }
```

I think this answer fixed your requirement.

Happy Coding

Comment: The second part, cellForItem at is in the parentCollectionViewCell right?

Comment: where will the bindassetID function go?

Comment: This is still confusing. Can we use hangouts so you can help me through this? Thanks

Comment: Can you mail me here! samir7kutty@gmail.com

Comment: sure... If you find anything useful please upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to detect the selected `UICollectionView` then you have to get the data from that cell, and do whatever with it, you can simply check that in the `didSelectRowAt` function and then do whatever with your data lets say for example you want to get something called `foo` from the sub cell and display it in the `Parent` cell, your code should be something like this,

```
 var myFooData: String?
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == parentCollectionView { // if the selected cell from the parent collection view do something

        } else {
            //if the selected cell from the sub collection view do something
        myFooData = (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MyCusomCell).MyFooData
        }
    }
```